# PHP can't execute shell from browser

Tags: php, git

I'm following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-perfect-workflow-with-git-github-and-ssh--net-19564).

I cannot get the `gitpull.php` script to execute a git pull when accessing the script through the browser.

I can manually execute a `git pull` from shell on my remote server.

I can manually run the php script:

```
<?php `git pull`;
```

which uses back ticks to run shell if I explicitly call the script in shell. `php gitpull.php`

I've checked permissions on the php file and the file belongs to `www-data` user. Why can I run the script through the shell but not the browser?

Comment: Have you tested to make sure that php on its own works properly? Just a simple `<?php echo "Hello world!";` should do.

Answer (score 0):

check path and permissions. also change owner to www-data if you are using a debian based distro.

```
ie: chown www-data:www-data scriptname
```

and check php error log for details.

Comment: error logs report: "Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists. Host key verification failed. fatal: could not read from remote repository." Which is odd because it will run if I manually execute the file in ssh. This is after chown user and group to www-data.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with how the ssh keys are setup for github. When I originally created the keys I was logged in as user1. Do the github ssh keys need to be created for the web user?

Comment: please use the command: su www-data when you are root, and try to run command directly. you'll see the error that php encounters.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the permissions of your web server.  The web server would need permissions to execute files.

What web server are you using?

Make sure that the file has the execute bit set.

Comment: World permission are set to read and execute. This is on Ubuntu running Apache2. Do you mean permissions on the file or are there permissions in a config file or php.ini that I missing? I believe safemode was removed from php5, which can prevent shell execution.

Comment: I wonder if git uses environment variables associated with your user account, when you run via the web server user those variables are not accessible.